Google Calendar API and Auth 2.0 server side
Good morning everyone,
I need to consult a calendar on GoogleCalendar via the dedicated API.
Specifically I need to make the freebusy call (returns all events pinned to a given calendar id).
To make this call you need to create an API key and Google Auth 2.0 (already enabled by Google Cloud Console).
If I configure the call on postman and authorize postman with auth 2.0 the call works.
I now need to make this call server side. So, on a specific calendar, make this call and get back the JSON with the response either in PHP or in JS.
I need to do server-side authentication as the customer will fill out the form and select one of the available dates on the calendar (without having to give access to his Google information).
The Google account where the operations are carried out is mine, therefore at a graphic and client level the customer who fills out the form must not be asked for access to Google.
Is there any procedure that can be performed to obtain the data necessary for server-side authentication without involving the customer?
freebusy call
Thank you
I tried to configure it in JS, but after a period of time the bearer token generated by Auth 2.0 expires and is not valid.

What api is deprecated exactly.   Calendar v3 is not deprecated.  please edit your question include [example] and show us the error you are getting.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
